# General Generics c#

Tags: c#, generics

So I have this test program:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1TEST{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new derp<int,int>(5,4);
    }
}

class derp<T,V>
{
    public T top;
    public V vop;

    public derp(T to, V vo)
    {
        top = to;
        vop = vo;
        top.ToString();
    }
}
```

}

`top.ToString` is allowed. As are `GetHashCode`, `GetType`, and `Equals`. However, `ToUpper` is not allowed, and neither are other string-specific methods.  Can this be changed?

When I place a method that is not allowed, this is the error I get:

> Error 1   'ConnectionServiceT' does not contain a definition for
>   'connect' and no extension method 'connect' accepting a first argument
>   of type 'ConnectionServiceT' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: if you want to use string, then do not use generics.there is no guarantee that `T` will be a string so you can't access the string methods on `T` and also you can't add a constraint because `string` class is sealed.

Comment: `GetHashCode, GetType, Equals` is not from type `string`, they are from type `object` which is base type of all `.NET` types.

Comment: Do you know about generic type constraint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx.

Comment: Why did you choose make derp generic?  What problem are you trying to solve with generics?

Comment: I'm using this as a general example, I don't really mean to use this exact code.

@Selman22, What is the difference between a sealed vs  an unsealed class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> top.ToString is allowed. GetHashCode, GetType, Equals is also allowed.
>
> However, ToUpper is not allowed, and other string-specific methods are not allowed. Can this be changed?

That's perfectly normal. The compiler knows nothing about the actual type of `T`, so it can't assume that it has a `ToUpper` method. However, since all types (except pointers) inherit from `Object`, calling methods of the `Object` class is allowed.

Now, if there was a constraint on `T` to force it to inherit a type that has a `ToUpper` method, your code would work:

```
class derp<T,V> where T : String
```

It's a bad example, because `String` is sealed, so this code wouldn't compile, but it's just to illustrate the idea.

Anyway, if you want to be able to call the `String.ToUpper` method on `top`, then the type of `top` cannot be generic: it *has* to be `String`.

To learn more about generic constraints, see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: @Selman22, I know, and I mentioned it in my answer... it was just to illustrate

Comment: Could you go a bit more into constraints?  What else can I put into the constraints?

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, I was just looking at it earlier, actaully, but I think I need a dumbed down version of it.

Comment: @EraZorX, basically, when you put no constraint on a generic type parameter, it means that it can be anything that derives from Object. Constraints just let you give more information about what type should be allowed, and the compiler takes that information into account to allow specific usages. For instance, if you constrain T to be IDisposable, you will be able to call Dispose on an instance of T.

Answer (score 2):

It is reasonable that the method `ToUpper()` is not allowed, since this is a method specific for string types. If your type isn't a string then you can't use the `ToUpper()` method, because this method is specific to string types.

On the other hand, since all types inherrit the object type, they  inherit it's methods,  which are `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`, `GetType()` and `Equals()`.

[This](http://n.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx) is a good link regarding the inheritance in C#, in where you can see more thoroughly what I am talking about.

Also [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kkx3h3c.aspx) is stated that:

> In the unified type system of C#, all types, predefined and user-defined, reference types and value types, inherit directly or indirectly from Object.

Answer (score 0):

.ToString() works on every type. If the type is not a string the type's name will be returned.
.ToUpper() is a string specific, won't work on types other than string.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be changed?

You don't know what `T` and `V` are, so the only assumption the compiler can make is that they inherit from `object`, which is why `ToString`, `GetHashCode`, `GetType`, and `Equals` are allowed (since they're methods on `object` which *every* class inherits from).

If `ConnectionServiceT` (and other similar classes) inherit from a base class you can constrain `T` and `V` to be subclasses of a given type:

```
class derp<T,V> where T:BaseService 
                where V:MyOtherClass
{
    public T top;
    public V vop;

    public derp(T to, V vo)
    {
        top = to;
        vop = vo;
        top.ToString();
    }
}
```

*Then* you can call methods specific to `BaseService` on instances of `T` (since you know that `T` must derive from `BaseService`.

But you can't constrain to `string` because it's sealed - the only possible class would be `derp<string, string>` so there's no reason to use generics.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing you cant use T`oUpper()`. You are sending in integers, those certainly do not have a ToUpper method. ToUpper is a method that belongs to string objects. You could do this:

```
string myUpperCaseString = top.ToString().ToUpper();

//or

if(top.GetType() == typeof(string)
{
    string myUpperCaseString = (top as string).ToUpper();
}
```

What you may have been mistaken about, is that `ToString()` does not change the string... it instead returns a new string representation of that object, you then have to store this object somewhere. Above I stored it in a variable called `myUpperCaseString` with the type of `string`.

ToString, GetHashCode, GetType are all methods that belong to the [object class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) and anything that inherits from it.